# If my datatype is varchar(100), why can't I insert data that is less than 100 characters?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

```
create table HallSchedule
(
     date varchar(10) not null,
     startTime varchar(4) not null,
     hallNo char(5) not null,
     cinemaName varchar(100) not null,

     primary key (date, startTime, hallNo, cinemaName),

     foreign key (cinemaName) references Cinema,
     foreign key (hallNo, cinemaName) references Hall
)
```

In this SQL table, I state that the datatype of `cinemaName is varchar(100)`, but whenever I try to insert values into `cinemaName`, this error occurs:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__HallSched__cinem__61316BF4". The conflict occurred in database "MovieAssignment2", table "dbo.Cinema", column 'CinemaName'.

Comment: as the error says "foreign key constraint". check that the value you are inserting exists in the Cinema table

Comment: It's because there is no row in the table `cinema` with that name

Comment: Did you read the error message? Content length of any column is irrelevant to the error you get...

Answer (score 3):

It is not a problem with length of the data, it is a problem with your `FOREIGN KEY constraint`. You are trying to add `cinemaName` that is not in your `Cinema` table.

As I can see from create script you provided you have a foreign key with table `Cinema` on the column `cinemaName`, so you need to add relevant data to `Cinema` table at first.

EDIT

Also you have `foreign key (hallNo, cinemaName) references Hall` so, basically you need to add relevant data here too. I bet you have same reference on `Hall` table too.

In my opinion it is a very bad design. Better have `Cinema` table, for each movie you will have an `id` (f.e. `id integer identity (1,1) not null`) that could be used in another tables. So you don't have to store movie full name in all tables.